# Service account is lacking privilige on windows domain when executing a script

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, privileges, service-accounts

I have scheduled a Powershell script to run in the task scheduler every morning. This script is looking into the disks of other machines in the local network and sends me an email of the remaining space.

It seems that the service account doesn't have the required privileges on the remote machines and it's sending me an empty email. There is no issue when I run the script using a domain admin account.

Do you know what kind of privilege do I need to configure on the remote machines for the service account to be able to access them?

Comment: Of what account are you talking exactly ("service account")? It might be a local account. Thus, it has nearly no priviliges on other machines. Why don't you use an extra domain account for this purpose, that has the proper privileges for this exact task?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Thomas. This is a domain user account. I've assigned the `Log on as batch job` privilege on the remote machine but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: If your sheduled task executes a PowerShell script, the account needs at least the `Log on as batch job` privilege on the **local** machine.